# twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError: User timeout caused connection failure

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to run this command:

```
scrapy shell "http://www.zomato.com/sao-paulo-sp/restaurants?page=1"
```

But I'm getting:

```
twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError: User timeout caused connection failure: Getting http://www.zomato.com/sao-paulo-sp/restaurants?page=1 took longer than 180.0 seconds..
```

this my scrapy version:

```
scrapy version -v
Scrapy       : 1.5.1
lxml         : 4.2.4.0
libxml2      : 2.9.8
cssselect    : 1.0.3
parsel       : 1.5.0
w3lib        : 1.19.0
Twisted      : 18.7.0
Python       : 2.7.10 (default, Jul 15 2017, 17:16:57) - [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)]
pyOpenSSL    : 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017)
cryptography : 1.9
Platform     : Darwin-17.3.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a connectivity issue. Start troubleshooting:

- did you intend to use http or https?
- does the page load when you paste the same URL into your browser?
- is scrapy behind some kind of proxy?
- can you use `curl -v ...` to download the page?
- is it possible that you are gettin throttled/blocked by zomato?